# Calculate Percent of Java Object that Represents Number of Attributes that are Filled

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, pojo

Consider a POJO have n attributes. How to get percentage value that represents the number of attributes that are filled (assigned value/Not Null) of the POJO? 
The POJO is an Entity in the MySql database and I'm using Java, Hibernate and Spring.

Comment: Where do you want to do this calculation?  In the database itself?  If you want to tally the fields of your POJO in Java that should be obvious how to do that.

Comment: Do you need to do this for just one class? If so the simplest way is to just write a method that checks each attribute in turn. If you need to check multiple classes then perhaps consider using reflection.

Comment: Please add what you've done/tried so far so we can actually help you, code examples are very helpful here. But I believe you can use reflection for this- it might not be the best way though, and I don't know if it even is usable because I've not used reflection yet myself. It may be worth investigating however.

Comment: I want to do in Java.

Comment: Have you even done anything yet?

Comment: @DonnachaConnolly I have did it using get each attribute for every class. But i want a solution that is generic and not want to add every new attribute that add to the class later.

Comment: That sounds like you'll need to use reflection.

Comment: Please post an example code for it.

Answer (score 2):

Hey You can do something like:

```
public class CountReflection {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

        PoJo p = new PoJo();
        p.setA("a");

        Field[] fields = p.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        int amountOfFields = 0;
        int amountOfFieldsNotNull = 0;

        for (Field field : fields) {
            amountOfFields++;
            Field declaredField = p.getClass().getDeclaredField(field.getName());
            declaredField.setAccessible(true);
            Object value = declaredField.get(p);
            if (value != null) {
                amountOfFieldsNotNull++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("amountOfFields " + amountOfFields);
        System.out.println("amountOfFieldsNotNull " + amountOfFieldsNotNull);
        float percent = (amountOfFieldsNotNull * 100.0f) / amountOfFields;
        System.out.println("percent of not null " + percent);
    }

}
```

With the PoJo:

```
public class PoJo {

    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private String d;
    private String e;

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(final String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(final String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(final String c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public String getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(final String d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public String getE() {
        return e;
    }

    public void setE(final String e) {
        this.e = e;
    }

}
```